# Can't get text to wrap around my table using wraptable (wrapfigure) and ragged2e

Tags: tables, floats, subfloats, wrapfigure, wrap

So I am fairly new to Latex and I am a bit clueless. I am trying to make text wrap around a table and I found useful packages, however I can't seem to make it work. My wraptable environment always seems to end up at the end of the text instead of where I place it. I suspect it has something to do with the \justify command that I specify at the beginning, because removing it makes it actually work just fine. However, this doesn't seem like a solution because I need my text to be justified.

So my question is, how do I get wrapfigure to work? Here are some working examples:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatflt}

\begin{document}
\justify
\section{Introduction} 

   \lipsum[1] 

\begin{wraptable}{l}{5cm}
\caption{Multilevel Linear Regression - Main Model Results}
\label{Table1}
\begin{tabular}{l c }
\hline
 & Model A1 \\
\hline
(Intercept)            & $\mathbf{43.53} \; (2.36)^{***}$  \\
Male (0/1)             & $\mathbf{-1.74} \; (0.39)^{***}$  \\
Age                    & $\mathbf{-4.59} \; (0.98)^{***}$  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
 \begin{tablenotes}
      \scriptsize
  \item $^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$, $^{\dagger}p<0.1$. 
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{wraptable} 

\lipsum[1] 

\section{Theory} 

\lipsum[1] 


\end{document}
```

Which leaves the table at the end of the text.

Comment: Don't mix floatflt and wrapfig, as they wind up fighting eash other.  BTW, the LaTeX command for justify is \fussy or \sloppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with the `plain TeX`  macro package `insbox`. It often works where `wrapfig` doesn't work well. There are problems to add a caption, for some reason I do not understand,but it is circumvented putting the  table/figure in a `minipage`, and using `\captionof` instead of `\caption`.

We have to use the `\InsertBoxL` command, which uses two mandatory arguments: the number of lines that remain untouched before inserting the box, and the contents of the box. We can use (lat argument) an optional argument, which is the number of supplementary lines to shorten, in case Tex does not calculate adequately the vertical space required for the insertion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum, caption, booktabs, threeparttable}
\input{insbox.tex}

\begin{document}
\justify
\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1]

\InsertBoxL{0}{
  \begin{minipage}{5.25cm}
    \captionsetup{skip=6pt, font=small}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \captionof{table}{Multilevel Linear Regression – Main Model Results}\label{Table1}
      \begin{tabular}{l c }
        \toprule
                    & Model A1 \\
        \midrule
        (Intercept) & $\mathbf{43.53} \; (2.36)^{***}$ \\
        Male (0/1) & $\mathbf{-1.74} \; (0.39)^{***}$ \\
        Age & $\mathbf{-4.59} \; (0.98)^{***}$ \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
        \smallskip \scriptsize
        \item $^{***}p<0.001$, $^{**}p<0.01$, $^*p<0.05$, $^{\dagger}p<0.1$.
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{minipage}}[4]

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi. Morbi
auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis vitae, ultricies et,
tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna,
vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse
ut massa. Cras nec ante. Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et
magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna.
Nulla ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.
Nulla malesuada porttitor diam. Donec felis erat, congue non, volutpat at,
tincidunt tristique, libero. Vivamus viverra fermentum felis. Donec nonummy
pellentesque ante. Phasellus adipiscing semper elit. Proin fermentum massa
ac quam. Sed diam turpis, molestie vitae, placerat a, molestie nec, leo. Mae-
cenas lacinia. Nam ipsum ligula, eleifend at, accumsan nec, suscipit a, ipsum.
Morbi blandit ligula feugiat magna. Nunc eleifend consequat lorem. Sed lacinia
nulla vitae enim. Pellentesque tincidunt purus vel magna. Integer non enim.
Praesent euismod nunc eu purus. Donec bibendum quam in tellus. Nullam cur-
sus pulvinar lectus. Donec et mi. Nam vulputate metus eu enim. Vestibulum
pellentesque felis eu massa.

\section{Theory}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I remember correctly `insbox` expects a box as its argument. `\caption` wouldn't be inside a box with `tabular` so it breaks `insbox`'s assumption. Therefore `minipage` (or something other which puts everything into a box) is required if you want a caption.

Comment: That's right. It also can be a \parbox or a `tabularx` – anything which allows line breaking.

Comment: I just noted this because you wrote "for some reason I do not understand..."

Comment: Oh! yes. You can't use `caption` (which is associated to floats). I don't know the details, but you have to use use `\captionof`.

Comment: That's because `figure` and `table` define `\@captype` and `\caption` checks whether this is defined. If not, it fails because it knows it's not used inside of a float. `\captionof` does only circumvent that by first defining `\@captype` and then calling `\caption`.

Comment: Oh, and if you don't need the features of `caption` except for `\captionof` you should use the `capt-of` package (much smaller -- also noted in the `caption`-documentation).

Comment: I know, but anyway I usually load caption, because it swaps the values of \abovecaptionskip and \belowcaptionskip in case the caption is above the float, which LaTeX doesn't do.