# How to wrap two tables?

Tags: tables, wrapfigure

I want to wrap two tables in latex. My code is the following:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}


\begin{wraptable}{l}
\begin{table}{H}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Topology - Distance function & ARI \\ \hline
Hextop - dist                &  0  \\
Hextop - mandist             &  0   \\
Randtop - dist               &  0   \\
Randtop - mandist            &  0   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Topology - Distance function & ARI \\ \hline
Hextop - dist                &  0   \\
Hextop - mandist             &  0   \\
Randtop - dist               &   0  \\
Randtop - mandist            &  0   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison of ARI score for grid 10 x 10 and 70 maximal number of epochs (left) and grid 61 x 61 and 10 maximal number of epochs (right)}
\end{table} 
\end{wraptable}
```

With the result of:

[image]

As you can see its wrapped correctly, however on the left side on the page there is sign `table[H]` and there is no caption in the table. I'm not sure how to improve it, I tried to build this table without using `\begin{table}` but I'm not sure how can I do it. Can I ask you for a hand in doing so?

Comment: You *definitely* need to drop the use of the `table` environment, since you're not planning on having the table float around.

Comment: you can not have a `table` enviornment in a wraptable (or any box) but please fix your example so that people can run it and see the issue and test answers. It is an incomplete fragment at present

Comment: you say it is "wrapped correctly" but you show no wrapping at all. The "wrap" in `wraptable` refers to wrapping an outer paragraph of text, making a "cut-out" for the table, unlike a standard table that comes between lines of text. You show no text at all outside the table so no possibility of it wrapping. see how the paragraph Nam dui... is cut out to wrap around the table here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361829/1090

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is two `tabular`s next to each other inside a `table` environment. So just get rid of the `wraptable`, and correct the `table` syntax.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Topology - Distance function & ARI \\ \hline
Hextop - dist                &  0  \\
Hextop - mandist             &  0   \\
Randtop - dist               &  0   \\
Randtop - mandist            &  0   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
Topology - Distance function & ARI \\ \hline
Hextop - dist                &  0   \\
Hextop - mandist             &  0   \\
Randtop - dist               &   0  \\
Randtop - mandist            &  0   \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Comparison of ARI score for grid 10 x 10 and 70 maximal number of epochs (left) and grid 61 x 61 and 10 maximal number of epochs (right)}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]